# MySQL select * from one table based on stock from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `oos_notify` and `temp_parts`.

The `oos_notify` table stores user information who signed up to recieve stock updates for a out of stock part. In the `oos_notify` table I am storing the users `email`, `part_id`, `datetime` and `email_sent` check field.

The `temp_parts table` stores part information with `part_id`, `part_name` and `stock`. (This is simplified).

What I am trying to do is select all the data from the `oos_notify` table only if the corresponding `part_id` in that table is in `stock` (`temp_parts.stock > 0`) from the `temp_parts` table.

This is what I have but it is returning all the `oos_notify` data which is wrong

```
SELECT * FROM oos_email_notify 
JOIN temp_parts ON temp_parts.code = oos_email_notify.part
WHERE temp_parts.stock >'0'
AND email_sent ='0'
```

Would it be possible to have some help on this. Thanks

Comment: To start with, you don't have to use quotes to indicate a number, as I assume you use int as type to store the stock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the link between the 2 tables is part_id, instead of code. 
 Try this.

```
SELECT * FROM oos_email_notify tbl1
JOIN temp_parts tbl2
ON tbl1.part_id = tbl2.part_id
WHERE tbl2.stock > 0
AND tbl1.email_sent = 0
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks that works perfectly! Thank you for your time. (EDIT) I will mark when I can, Thanks again